# How to keep the muted role when a muted user leaves the server and rejoins?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am working on a discord.py bot and I have found a problem. When a muted user leaves the server and rejoins, the muted role is gone for that user.

This is my mute/unmute command:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member, *, reason=None):
      guild = ctx.guild
      mutedRole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Muted")    
      await member.add_roles(mutedRole, reason=reason)

      embed=discord.Embed(title="Muted.")
      embed.add_field(name="Muted.", value=(f"Muted {member.mention} for reason {reason}"))                     
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      await member.send(f"You were muted in the server {guild.name} for {reason}")
      list_of_muted_members.append(member)
      print(list_of_muted_members)

@bot.command(description="Unmutes a specified user.")
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
      mutedRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")

      embed=discord.Embed(title="You have been unmuted.")
      embed.add_field(name="Unmuted.", value=(f"Unmuted {member.mention} Reason: {reason}"))
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      await member.remove_roles(mutedRole)
      await member.send(f"You were unmuted in the server {ctx.guild.name}")
```

Comment: Hello ! 
Do you have a database

Comment: Nope i don't have database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of doing it would be to store users that are currently muted in a .json file then you can reference that file when the user rejoins the server.

```
{
   "USERID": true
}
```

Then you could just:

```
with open('JSONFILE.json', 'r') as f:
  jsonfile = json.load(f)
  try:
     status = jsonfile[str(user.id)]
     if status:
        # add role to member
  except:
     # user wasn't found in json
     return
```

Comment: Gave me an idea on what to do :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make a simple database holding the user IDs for the muted users then query it whenever a user rejoins the group.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a list with all muted members and every time a possible new member joins go through this list and if the member is in there just add the muted role again.